# .NET Stops on sorting and Icompare()

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a problem with sorting and `IComparer()`. My program stops on it. I'm a beginner with C#. 
Here is the part of the code where it stops:

```
public ArrayList ModelSort()
            {
                IComparer sorter = new R2SortHelper();
                InnerList.Sort(sorter);
                return InnerList;
            }

            private class R2SortHelper : System.Collections.IComparer
            {
                public int Compare(object x, object y)
                {
                    double m1 = ((Model)x).R2() + ((Model)x).Valid().GetHashCode();
                    double m2 = ((Model)y).R2() + ((Model)y).Valid().GetHashCode();

                    if (m1 > m2)
                        return -1;
                    else if (m1 < m2)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
            }
```

Here is an error from console:

```
Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results. IComparer: 'AMO.EnPI.AddIn.Utilities.ModelCollection+R2SortHelper'.
```

List of exceptions:

**Exception Text**

> System.ArgumentException: Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results. IComparer: 'AMO.EnPI.AddIn.Utilities.ModelCollection+R2SortHelper'.
>          at System.Array.SorterObjectArray.DepthLimitedQuickSort(Int32 left, Int32 right, Int32 depthLimit)
>          at System.Array.SorterObjectArray.DepthLimitedQuickSort(Int32 left, Int32 right, Int32 depthLimit)
>          at System.Array.Sort(Array keys, Array items, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer comparer)
>          at System.Collections.ArrayList.Sort(Int32 index, Int32 count, IComparer comparer)
>          at System.Collections.ArrayList.Sort(IComparer comparer)
>          at AMO.EnPI.AddIn.Utilities.ModelCollection.ModelSort() in C:\ENPI\EnPI\AMO.EnPI-5.0\AMO.EnPI.Utilities\Analytics.cs:line 961
>          at AMO.EnPI.AddIn.ModelSheet.WriteResultsTable(Int32 n, Boolean top) in C:\ENPI\EnPI\AMO.EnPI-5.0\AMO.EnPI.AddIn\ModelSheet.cs:line 146
>          at AMO.EnPI.AddIn.ModelSheet.Populate() in C:\ENPI\EnPI\AMO.EnPI-5.0\AMO.EnPI.AddIn\ModelSheet.cs:line 60
>          at AMO.EnPI.AddIn.ThisAddIn.plotEnPI(ListObject LO) in C:\ENPI\EnPI\AMO.EnPI-5.0\AMO.EnPI.AddIn\ThisAddIn.cs:line 318
>          at AMO.EnPI.AddIn.RegressionControl.runFunction(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\ENPI\EnPI\AMO.EnPI-5.0\AMO.EnPI.AddIn\RegressionControl.cs:line 817
>          at AMO.EnPI.AddIn.CO2EmissionControl.btnCalculate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\ENPI\EnPI\AMO.EnPI-5.0\AMO.EnPI.AddIn\CO2EmissionControl.cs:line 148

My model class:

```
public class Model
    {
    public int ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public double[] Ys { get; set; }
    public double[,] Xs { get; set; }
    public string[] VariableNames { get; set; }

    public double RMSError { get; set; }

    public double[] Coefficients { get; set; }

    public Model()
    {
        ModelNumber = 0;
        Ys = null;
        Xs = null;
        VariableNames = null;
        RMSError = 0;
        Coefficients = null;
    }
    public Model(int ModelNumber, double[] Ys, double[,] Xs, string[] VariableNames)
    {
        RMSError = 0;
        Coefficients = null;

        // run LLS
        int info;
        double[] c;
        alglib.lsfitreport rep;
        try
        {
            alglib.lsfitlinear(Ys, Xsplusone(), out info, out c, out rep);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        Coefficients = c;
        RMSError = rep.rmserror;
    }

    public void Run() //double[] Ys, double[,] Xs, string[] VariableNames)
    {
        RMSError = 0;
        Coefficients = null;

        if (Ys != null && Xs != null)
        {
            // run LLS
            int info;
            double[] c;
            alglib.lsfitreport rep;
            try
            {
                alglib.lsfitlinear(Ys, Xsplusone(), out info, out c, out rep);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            Coefficients = c;
            RMSError = rep.rmserror;
        }
    }

    public int N()
    {
        return Ys.Count();
    }

    public int df()
    {
        return N() - k() - 1;
    }

    public int k()
    {
        return VariableNames.Count();
    }

    public double TotalSS()
    {
        // compute total sum of squares
        double ybar = Ys.Average();
        double sst = 0;
        for (int i = Ys.GetLowerBound(0); i <= Ys.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            sst += Math.Pow(Ys[i] - ybar, 2);
        }

        return sst;
    }

    public double ResidualSS ()
    {
        return ( N() * Math.Pow( RMSError, 2));
    }

    public double R2()
    {
        return (1 - (ResidualSS() / TotalSS()));
    }

    public double AdjustedR2()
    {
         return (1 - (((1 - R2()) * (N() - 1)) / (N() - k() - 1)));

    }

    public double F()
    {
        return ( (R2() / k()) / ((1 - R2()) / (N() - k() - 1)));
    }

    public double ModelPValue()
    {
        double modelP = 0;
        double modelF = F();
        if (modelF < 0) modelF = 0;

        try
        {
            modelP = alglib.fcdistribution(N() - df() - 1, df(), modelF);

        }
        catch (alglib.alglibexception e)
        {
        }
        return modelP;
    }

    public bool Valid()
    {
        // Model validity criteria, from the SEP M&V protocol:
        // The model p-value must be less than 0.1
        // All variables must have p-values less than 0.2
        // At least one variable must have a p-value of less than 0.1
        // The R2 value must be greater than 0.5

        double[] ps = PValues();
        bool varsvalid = true;
        bool varlowexists = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < ps.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (ps[i] <= Constants.PVALUE_THRESHOLD)
                varlowexists = true;
            if (ps[i] > Constants.PVALUE_HIGH)
                varsvalid = false;
        }

        if (!varlowexists)
            return false;

        if (!varsvalid)
            return false;

        if (ModelPValue() > Constants.PVALUE_THRESHOLD)
            return false;

        if (R2() < Constants.R2VALUE_MIN)
            return false;

        return true;

    }

    public string Formula()
    {
        string formula = "";
        int offset = Coefficients.GetLowerBound(0) - VariableNames.GetLowerBound(0);
        for (int i = Coefficients.GetLowerBound(0); i < Coefficients.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
             formula += "(" + Coefficients[i].ToString("0.0000") + " * " + ExcelHelpers.CreateValidFormulaName(VariableNames[i - offset]) + ") + ";
            // formula += "(" + Coefficients[i].ToString() + " * " + ExcelHelpers.CreateValidFormulaName(VariableNames[i - offset]) + ") + ";
        }

        formula += Coefficients[Coefficients.GetUpperBound(0)].ToString("0.00");

        return formula;
    }

    public double[,] Xsplusone()
   {
       return DataHelper.arrayAddIdentity(Xs, 0, 1); // add on a column of ones for the intercept
   }

    public double[] PredictedYs()
   {            // compute the predicted ys
       double[] yhat = new double[N()];
       double[,] xs = Xsplusone();
       double[] c = Coefficients;

       for (int i = 0; i < N(); i++)
       {
           yhat[i] = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j < k() + 1; j++)
           {
               yhat[i] += xs[i, j] * c[j];
           }
       }

       return yhat;
   }

    public double[,] CovarianceMatrix()
   {
       // compute the coefficient covariance matrix
       double[,] twodYs = DataHelper.dbl2DArray(Ys);
       double[,] XYs = DataHelper.dblarrayUnion(Xs, twodYs);
       double[,] cov;
       int info;
       alglib.linearmodel lm;
       alglib.lrreport rpt;

       try
       {
           alglib.lrbuild(XYs, N(), k(), out info, out lm, out rpt);
           cov = rpt.c;
       }
       catch
       {
           throw;
       }

       return cov;
   }

    public double[] StandardErrors()
    {
       // compute the x std errors and p-values
       double[,] cov = CovarianceMatrix();
       double[] se = new double[k()];

       if (cov.GetLength(0) > 0 && cov.GetLength(1) > 0)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < k(); j++)
           {
               se[j] = Math.Sqrt(cov[j, j]);
           }
       }

       return se;
   }

    public double[] PValues()
   {
       double[] c = Coefficients;
       double[,] cov = CovarianceMatrix();
       double[] se = StandardErrors();
       double[] pv = new double[k()];

       if (cov.GetLength(0) > 0 && cov.GetLength(1) > 0)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < k(); j++)
           {
               se[j] = Math.Sqrt(cov[j, j]);
               try
               {
                   pv[j] = 2 * (1 - alglib.studenttdistribution(df(), Math.Abs(c[j] / se[j])));
               }
               catch
               {
               }
           }
       }

       return pv;
   }

    public string AICFormula()
    {
        return "";
    }

    //Added By Suman for SEP Validation changes
    public string[] SEPValidationCheck()
    {
        string[] sepChk = new string[k()];
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < sepChk.Length; cnt++)
        {
            if (Valid() == true)
            {
                sepChk[cnt] = "Pass";
            }
            else
            {
                sepChk[cnt] = "Fail";
            }
        }
        return sepChk;
    }
}
```

Here is GetHashCode():

```
public override int GetHashCode() 
        { 
            return x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode(); 
        }
```

My R2():

```
public double R2()
        {
            return (1 - (ResidualSS() / TotalSS()));
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare HashCodes?

Comment: Add code for Model class here also.

Comment: Additionally, shouldn't you be using `m1.CompareTo(m2)`? Though in your case, you'd need to multiply by -1 to get the same order

Comment: GetHashCode() is a function of which class in your code?

Comment: As I said in my answer, your GetHashCode() is not sortable.

Comment: I am updating my answer based on the extra code.

Answer (score 3):

For the majority of types, you can't sort by GetHashCode() since the hash code calculations aren't necessarily going to sort in the same order as the value. You can only sort on GetHashCode() reliably when it is the value itself (such as int), but at that point there isn't any point in getting the hash code since you already have the value. Also you didn't show what R2() and Valid() methods do, so who knows what kind of unholyness is going on in there.

EDIT (OP updated code):

Your GetHashCode() usage is definitely not sortable. Nor is adding a boolean to a double. 5 + 0 vs. 2 + 1 is not going to sort correctly (assuming you want the falses up front?)

Just use ((Model)x).R2() vs ((Model)y).R2() as the comparison, if you want the falses or trues up front, you can add something like:

```
if (x.Valid && !y.Valid)
   return 1;
if (!x.Valid && y.Valid)
   return -1;

//then do your R2 comparisons here.
```

That preamble will cause the non valids to always come first and then sort by R2s. You can reverse if you want to go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Your .Valid() method is returning boolean, and then you go to find hash code. Is this expected from your code? 
Basically, you are doing `some double value + boolean.GetHashCode()`. Solution would be to not use .Valid() in your right side expression. Check that separately.

```
         private class R2SortHelper : System.Collections.IComparer
            {
                public int Compare(object x, object y)
                {
                    Model xModel = (Model)x;
                    Model yModel = (Model)y; 
                   if((Model.Valid()==true) && (yModel.Valid()==true))
                    { 
                    double m1 = xModel.R2() + xModel.GetHashCode();
                    double m2 = yModel.R2() + yModel.GetHashCode();
                    return (m1 > m2) ? -1 : ((m1 < m2) ? 1 :0);   
                    }
                   return 0;
               }
          }
```